# Reading XSL file from project directory instead of local drive in Mule

Tags: mule

I am using XSLT transformer component in Mule Studio. Till now, I am reading the .xsl file from my local drive. But ,I want to make it system independent and read the xsl sheet from classpath.

Any suggestions on what to mention in the path?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/XSLT+Transformer), the **xsl-file** attribute is:

> The full path to the XSL template file to use when performing the
>   transformation. This can be a path on the local file system or on the
>   classpath. This attribute is not required if the <xslt-text>
>   element has been set.

Therefore you should be able to specify a classpath resource with it.

Comment: I have read that too. But, I want to know how to configure the xml to read it.

Comment: What about: <xslt-transformer xsl-file="file_on_your_classpath.xsl" /> ?

Comment: nope...I have tried it earlier also, but it doesn't identify the path.

Comment: Are you sure the XSL file is in the classpath? Is it at the root of the classpath?